# Add toc on 3rd page using apache XWPF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to add table of contents(toc) on 3rd page of Doc using apache XWPF.

```
Here is the code below : 

XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

CTSdtBlock block = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSdt();
           TOC toc = new TOC(block);
                 toc.addRow(3, "toc", 3, "16283778");
        doc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("toc.docx")));
```

Comment: This is a duplicate because any attempt to customize the Table of Contents can be handled as in the accepted answer. If you can't figure out this particular customization after reading the duplicate question and answer, edit this question with your specific point of confusion in relation to the linked question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a `paragraph` in your document with a `run`. That way you can add `BreakType.PAGE` to your `paragraphs`.

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
```

`BreakType.PAGE` skips a page

Comment: can you please provide full code

Comment: See my edited post. Try to impelement this to your own code. @Aman Kumayu